# How to work with permissions in single activity design using navigation component?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-permissions

My previous app has many activities and some of them are declared as exported true, so that other apps can call them through intent filter.
Some of them also has specific permission which also sets in my activities.

Now, i am developing a app using single activity.
So, i am curious to know how can i handle this permission issue in single activity design, as i have only one activity.

Previously, in multiple activities i can easily set permission in specific activity. How can i handle this here?
I am a newbie. I searched a lot but did not find any clue.

**Edit:**

```
    Multiple activities declaration:

    <permission
      android:name="com.example.permission"
      android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"
      tools:ignore="SignatureOrSystemPermissions" 
    />

    // Activity 1: With permission, exported = true
    <activity
        android:name=".place"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="place"
        android:permission="com.example.permission" // Sets a permission
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.action.places" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    // Activity 2: With no permission, exported = true

      <activity
        android:name="userCheck"
        android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.confirm.passowrd" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

Now, i want to move to single activity.

```
   // Single activity: exported = true. How can i handle permission for place action?
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.singleActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <!-- Place -->
            <action android:name="com.action.places"/> // How can i handle permission for this action?

            <!-- UserCheck -->
            <action android:name="com.confirm.passowrd" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If your app has only one `Activity` then you need to request all your permissions from that `Activity`. Or are you asking about your own custom permissions needed to access your activities? Please edit your question and give us an example of what you are having trouble with.

Comment: @DavidWasser Please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use manifest-based permissions if you want to restrict a single `Activity` from being launched in some cases but not others. The manifest-based permission controls access to the specific `Activity`, no matter how it is being launched.

What you could do is create an `<activity-alias>` for your single `Activity`. An `<activity-alias>` is a manifest entry that references an actual `Activity`, but provides alternate launch options. You can specify a different set of permissions on the `<activity-alias>` than the ones you have on the actual `Activity`. You can also specify different `launchMode`, different `<intent-filter>`, etc.

Comment: I have faced another issue in single activity design. Would you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625479/how-to-work-with-preference-in-single-activity-design-using-navigation-component

Comment: I am facing an issue with permission for actvity-alias. Would you please check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65889015/how-to-start-activity-alias-of-another-app-which-has-permission