# How to start activity-alias of another app which has permission?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-permissions, android-activity-alias

I have an app which has an activity and activity-alias. I am trying to call this activity from another app through activity-alias but it crashes when i add permission in activity-alias. If no permission is added, it works fine.

```
     <permission
       android:name="com.USE_SASETTINGS"
       android:protectionLevel="normal" />

     <activity android:name=".DemoActivity"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name=".demoAlias"
        android:exported="true"
        android:targetActivity="DemoActivity"
        android:permission="com.USE_SASETTINGS">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.accountsettingone"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity-alias>
```

From another app, i am trying to call the activity through activity-alias.

```
Manifest of another app:

 <uses-permission android:name="com.USE_SASETTINGS"/>

Activity of another app:    
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      startActivity(new Intent("com.example.accountsettingone"));
  }
```

}

But application crashes. Error message:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.testpermissionsingleactiivty, PID: 24625
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testpermissionsingleactiivty/com.example.testpermissionsingleactiivty.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=com.example.accountsettingone cmp=com.example.app.test/com.example.app.test.demoAlias } from ProcessRecord{9b35008 24625:com.example.testpermissionsingleactiivty/u0a187} (pid=24625, uid=10187) requires com.USE_SASETTINGS
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3610)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3756)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8037)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=com.example.accountsettingone cmp=com.example.app.test/com.example.app.test.demoAlias } from ProcessRecord{9b35008 24625:com.example.testpermissionsingleactiivty/u0a187} (pid=24625, uid=10187) requires com.USE_SASETTINGS
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2088)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
    at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:4469)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1716)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5258)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5203)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5587)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5555)
    at com.example.testpermissionsingleactiivty.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3585)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3756) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8037) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100) 
 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1401)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:936)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:716)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:2004)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:630)
```

I am newbie. Eagerly waiting for feedback.

Comment: Did you install the test app BEFORE you installed the app with `<activity-alias>`? To be sure, uninstall both apps. Install the app with `<activity-alias>`. Then install the other app. See if that helps. The crash indicates that the app that is crashing does not have the required permission, even though it is mentioned in the manifest.

Comment: Also, you might want to define a `label` and a `description` for your custom permission. The documentation seems to imply that these are required. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining